# React Native TextInput Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, textinput

I created 3 text inputs in a page. Yesterday all the text inputs works fine but when I run the app today the last input which Password is not working. When I click on the last text input it does not pop up the keyboard and if I remove the Password input then the email input stops working. Please help me to solve the problem. Here is the image:

[image]

Code.....

```
<View style={styles.SignUpSetting}>
                    <Text style={styles.createAccountTxt}>Create Account</Text>
                    <View style={styles.inputSetting}>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTxt}>Full Name</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={fname} onChangeText={text => setFName(text)} placeholder="e.g: Muhammad Ali" placeholderTextColor={'#000'} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputSetting}>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTxt}>Email Address</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={email} onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)} placeholder="e.g: abc@gmail.com" placeholderTextColor={'#000'} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputSetting}>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTxt}>Password</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={password} onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)} placeholder="e.g: vf@kHY" placeholderTextColor={'#000'} secureTextEntry={true} />
                    </View>
</View>
```

styling....

```
inputSetting: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        top: 60,
        left: 28,
        margin: 8,
    },
    inputTxt: {
        color: '#a1a1a1',
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        top: 5,
        borderColor: '#9038A5',
        borderWidth: 0.6,
        width: 340,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        color: '#000',
    },
```

Comment: If it was working yesterday, but not today, it could be an environment issue. Try deleting the node modules folder in your project and reinstalling.

Comment: I uninstall the node modules and then reinstall but still not working

Comment: Try to run in real device.

Comment: Are you closing out that opening view tag? It's possible that you have something wrong syntactically further down the document.

Comment: Yes, I am closing all the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in my emulator. It works fine in my case.

[image: Keyboad is shown]
**Possible Solution(s):**

0. If you're using an emulator then 1st try it on your real device.
1. Double-check your code.
2. Try to restart the emulator and/or android studio.
3. Try to re-install the app.

Comment: I created a new project and run this project again. Every thing runs very well but still last textinput is not working.

Comment: What went wrong? I mean what is meant by "is not working"?

Comment: Means when I click on the last TextInput the keyboard is not pop up and when I click on the above 2 TextInputs the keyboard pops up. If I remove the Password TextInput which is the last input then the Email TextInput does not pops up the keyboard.

Comment: share your GitHub repo link. I'll try in my machine.

Comment: try   autoFocus={true}

Comment: I did not create GitHub repo. The problem is only in Signup page. I have tried your suggestions as well as others but nothing work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251871/discussion-between-hafiz-muhammad-zohair-ajmal-and-muhammad-faraz-ali).